# Opencv crashes at start in Android

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm new with opencv on Android. My goal is to make an app that can make a perspective correction but i'm facing some problems. Sometimes, (randomly, I think ) the app fails to start. I don't understand why. 
Here are the lines i've obtained from Logcat.

It starts with something like this:

```
12-24 13:11:30.352 15278-15278/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-24 13:11:30.536 15278-15289/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/art: humin current process: com.example.tiago.pdiandroid
12-24 13:11:30.537 15278-15289/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/art: current process_level is : 0
12-24 13:11:30.618 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.196 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.251 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.305 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.359 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.412 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.461 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.510 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.563 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.610 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.663 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.tiago.pdiandroid-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-24 13:11:31.703 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
12-24 13:11:31.703 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/MultiDex: Installing application
12-24 13:11:31.703 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
12-24 13:11:31.728 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
12-24 13:11:31.730 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
```

And ends:

```
12-24 13:11:31.912 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/OCVSample::Activity: OpenCV loaded successfully
12-24 13:11:31.918 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-24 13:11:31.994 15278-15321/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-24 13:11:32.125 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid E/Camera: Camera new cameraInitNormal:0
12-24 13:11:32.159 15278-15289/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/art: current process_level is : 0
12-24 13:11:32.181 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/OCVSample::Activity: Width: 1440
12-24 13:11:32.181 15278-15278/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/OCVSample::Activity: Height: 1080
12-24 13:11:33.274 15278-15351/com.example.tiago.pdiandroid I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15278 SIG: 9
```

I suspect that this last signal is what is killing my app but I don't know where it comes from.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some code snippet around where this random error appears to erupt?

Comment: If it is helpful I can add all the main activity. Anyway, to be honest, I don't know where the error appears.

Comment: Place Debug points at start of each method to narrow down the method after which the crash is happening, Then further put break points on the lines of that method.